# Very Basic iPhone App is Aburdly Large when installed on Device - over 200MB's

Tags: iphone, xcode, size

I'm pretty knew to coding, so apologies if I missed something painfully obvious.

I've created a very basic app - it's pretty much just string of UITableView's that the user navigates through to retrieve data.  There are 25 table view controllers attached to 7 navigation controllers, and an additional 7 view controllers.  I have a few png's for cell icon's and background images, etc, but taken all together these png's are less than 5 MB's.

The raw data is stored as a txt file in JSON format, and the files all together are less than 3 MB's.

At one point I had 65 pdf's stored in the app, and many of these were very large - some were over 3 or 4 MB's.  But I recently put these on the back end in parse.com and deleted them from the app entirely, so there are no more pdf's to take up memory.

Now, despite all this, when I load the app onto my iPhone, the app is taking up 234 MB's of memory, which is completely nuts and no different than when the 65 pdf's were still in the program.

I've searched all through the app's files and can't find anything that would account for this bloated size. I've checked and double checked that the pdf files have been removed, and there is no trace of them.  I deleted the files themselves, not just the reference to them in X-Code. I've tried restarting the computer in case there was some sort of cache in X-Code that needed to be cleared.  I've deleted and reinstalled the app on my phone numerous times, in case there were some residual files left from previous versions.  No good.  App is still over 200 MB's

Any thoughts on why my app would be over 200 MB's when installed on a device?

Comment: Not sure about the etiquette of answering one's own questions in SO, but I found the solution to my problem, so I'm posting it in case any one else has this issue.  Turns out my suspicion was right - it was a caching issue.  Went to the following folders: Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Derived Data. Cleared the derived data folder.  This contained every file that I had ever included in the app, and was including them with every build.  Obviously I was a little nervous about deleting stuff, but it worked.  Now the app is 14.5 MB's, down from 234 - much better!

Comment: when the errors seems to persist even after your logical efforts its time to delete derived data ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean project from precompiled files (Product -> clean or cmd+shift+k).
And delete derived data:
Open xcode organizer (window -> organizer or (cmd+shift+2) in projects tab find your project and press delete derived data. It should help.